# Settings for Transmission reset after reboot

Tags: kodi, openelec

I am running Transmission on OpenELEC v4.2.1 on a RPi model B. Every time I reboot the RPi the download location, queue size, download number and all other settings are reset to their default values.

Is there a file I can edit to permanently set my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last comment here solved the same problem for me:
http://openelec.tv/forum/78-transmission-bt-client/10992-transmission-settings-not-saved?start=45#126954

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the transmission config file, that is usually located in:

- For the GTK+ client, all settings are kept in
  `$HOME/.config/transmission`
- For the Daemon, all settings are kept in
  `$HOME/.config/transmission-daemon`
- For the CLI, all settings are kept
  in `$HOME/.config/transmission-cli`
- The default download folder is `$HOME/Downloads`

It's a JSON file, you should edit the `download-dir`, `download-queue-size`, and the other related settings.

Refer to [this docs](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/EditConfigFiles) for an explanation of all the settings.